# How to spread things out evenly

Tags: modeling

I was wondering how to spread things out evenly. When I look it up I only find things about aligning them, not about distributing them evenly. Here's a image to help explain [image: 157f9241714c3909016f90a558230828]

I want those three to be distributed evenly

Comment: You can use Snapping (`Shift`+`Tab`): *Vertex* or *Edge* if base mesh has adjacent loopcuts that are distributed evenly as you'd like, or *Grid* to snap to grid (better to be in ortographic mode to set up properly)

Answer (score 8):

All the other answers are work-arounds when you want a single button solution like in Adobe Illustrator and others.

The solution you want is in the addon called Oscurart Tools. The link to the addon is here: http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/3D_interaction/Oscurart_Tools

It comes with many features but the one you want is the second button from the bottom in the Object section.

[image]

**Addon Download tip**: The wiki page links to a list of separate file links that you have to download separately. Once you download them all, put them in a folder labelled "oscurart_tools" and then make a zip file from that. You can then import the addon from file this way for ease of use.

Answer (score 4):

You may do it using the ***Particle System***.
[image]

Add a mesh you want to spread the other objects on and divide it as many times you want (one object will be attached to one face). Add an object that will be spread. Name it ***Object***. 
[image]

Add a ***Particle System*** to the divided mesh. Choose ***Hair*** as a *Type*, check the ***Advanced*** box and set the Emission number to (in this case) 4. Under *Emit From:* check the ***Faces*** button. Check the ***Even Distribution*** box and change the *Random* to ***Jittered***. Change the ***Particles/Face*** amount to 1 (there will be one particle per one face displayed). Go to the *Render* panel, press the ***Object*** button, and input ***Object*** below, near the *Dupli Object:* window. Don't forget to check the ***Rotation*** box below.
[image]

Now rotate your spread object to adjust particles rotation.
[image]

Resize the particles using the *Size* slider in a *Phisics* panel or changing the size of the object you spread.
[image]

Go to the *Modifiers header* and click on ***Convert*** to convert the particles to the editable meshes.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I would go to Scene tab in Properties panel and in the Units section, change the units from None to Metric

[image]

Then I would check Length in the (N)Panel in the Mesh Display section

*( *this should be done in edit mode of the mesh* )

[image]

And then I would divide the length of the cyllinder by 4 and place the objects after each time the length is presented (red spots).

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I would use the array modifier and the boolean modifier. Object A is the base object and object B is the object you use to cut the holes out. Make sure you apply the rotation and scale on both objects <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>.  On object B, I add the array modifier and set it to a constant offset over the Z in this case 1.5m and set the count to 3. I can still change this as long as I don't apply it. Then I go to object A and add a boolean modifier set the operation to difference and set object to object B. Then I copy object A and B to an other layer in case I want to change it.
I apply the boolean modifier on object A and delete object B, and clean up the mesh.

[image]

[image]