# Emit Hair Particle from Center of Face

Tags: modeling, particles

How can I emit objects from the center of a face, as shown?

[image: Face-Centered Object]

When I try to emit from faces, they are randomly distributed.  None of the settings seem to allow for a placement of one object per face, evenly spaced.  This is how it looks:

[image: Randomly-Centered Object]

As you can see, the objects are indeed spawning on the faces, but there are issues: some faces have multiple objects, others have none, and all are randomly positioned on their planes.

Emitting from vertices behaves in the desired fashion:

[image: Vertex-Centered Object]

How can I achieve this behavior with face-centered object placement?

Comment: Related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/45426/center-objects-with-particle-system

Comment: The number of Hair particles has to match the face count of your object, right?

Comment: Please see my related answer here: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34937/how-to-spread-things-out-evenly

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To make particles emitted evenly from each face's center set up the next things:

1. Uncheck *Random* in Particle System settings (which you already did, still for completeness).
2. Make sure the object which will be used as particle instance has origin in the center of its geometry.
   *If you don't this still will work but when scaling particles' size it will grow somewhat unexpected*.
3. Set *Particles/Face* to 1 in Particle System settings (by default 0, i.e. automatic selection). This will mean that you ask particle system to emit only 1 particle per emitter's face.

   [image: particle system settings]

   [image: particles emitted from each face example]

   This will work in a similar way for *Emitter* type of Particle System too.
4. Number of particles - in order all this to work it has to be not less than total number of faces of the emitter. It may be higher though (doesn't matter how much, Particle System will automaticallsy cut what's not needed).
   This behaviour is less predictable if *Even Distribution* in Particle System settings is left being turned on. In order to make number of particles *exactly* fit amount of faces uncheck this option.

Comment: Now I realize that I was simply misreading one of the parameter labels - I had "Particles / Face" set to 32 thinking it was total number of particles.

Since this question was based on a simple misunderstanding, should I delete it?

Comment: @splic I think you shouldn't delete question because we all learn things, sometimes on errors, hence it can serve as a guide for further reference. Note that this site assumes providing useful information not only for questioner but also for future readers (like wiki).

Comment: thx for not deleting, I got reminded to turn of "random" because of this post.

Answer (score 11):

A simpler alternative implementation of this design utilizes **duplifaces**.

Ensure that the duplicated object (in this case, the cone) has its origin at its base.

1. Parent the duplicated object to the host object.
2. Enable duplication faces in the object tab of the parent object.
3. Scale and rotate the child object if necessary.
4. Make the duplicates real.
5. Delete the base child object.
6. Join the duplicates to the host if desired.

[image: GIF of the process]