# Is it possible to duplicate objects along the surface of a sphere?

Tags: bezier-curves

Let's say I'm trying to create a spherical object comprised of identical units along the face of the sphere (creating a model of a spherical cyst with cells making up the outer epithelium). How would I be able to copy the single cell I made and duplicate it so that it forms a sphere?

Comment: Hello and welcome :). I believe this thread could help you https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/50695/78972

Comment: Could you add a picture of the identical object you are trying to make a sphere from?