# How to attach leaves to branches quickly

Tags: modeling

I was hoping I could use blender to create a low-poly tree with leaves, is there some way I can do as I've done in the image, but witout placing, scaling, rotating, manually? this is killing me...

[image]

Comment: Hello :). I'd try using a particle system, emitting particles from faces. And use vertex paint to select the emitting areas. No time to post a full answer, but [this thread could help](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/50695/78972).