# Is it possible to emit hair particles from vertices as objects without overlap?

Tags: particles

I'm trying to construct a low-poly deathstar-type surface using a collection of square panels randomly placed along a surface. I'm using a hair particle system, render as collection, emitting from vertices, however due to the random placement of the objects some vertices of the surface get no panels and some vertices get more than 1 panel.

Is it possible with the particle system to specify that only 1 object should be put at each vertex of the surface?

[image: Screenshot showing the particle system placing panels]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First activate the *Statistics* option in the *Viewport Overlays*, so that you know how many vertices your object has:

[image]

[image]

Now in the *Particles panel > Emission > Number*, type the exact same number, and under *Source* make sure that *Random Order* is disabled:

[image]

[image]

[Here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50695/emit-hair-particle-from-center-of-face) the answer for emitting one particle by face.